# How can I create a dynamically sized array of linked lists?

Tags: c++, arrays, list

I need to create an array of linked lists at runtime for a hash table assignment.  The sample code that we are given only allows for creating arrays of static size, and I cannot figure out how to modify it to work with a variable, as everything I have tried has resulted in errors.

Sample Code:

```
typedef std::list<int> INT_LIST;
typedef INT_LIST* INT_LIST_POINTER;
int size = 13;
INT_LIST_POINTER myArray[size];
INT_LIST_POINTER tmpPtr;
// initialize the array to point to empty lists
for (int i=0; i<size; i++){
tmpPtr = new INT_LIST;
myArray[i] = tmpPtr;
}
```

My Current, nonworking Code:

```
typedef std::list<int> INT_LIST;
typedef INT_LIST* INT_LIST_POINTER;
INT_LIST_POINTER myArray = new INT_LIST[p];
INT_LIST_POINTER tmpPtr;
for (int i=0; i<n; i++){
INT_LIST* temp = new INT_LIST;
myArray[i] = temp;
}
```

The major problem seems to be with

```
myArray[i] =  temp;
```

which says nothing matches those operands.

Comment: check out `std::vector.resize` and `std::vector.push_back` methods.

Comment: If you want to wind up your teacher, point out that the sample code is not valid C++. It should be `const int size = 13;`. To demonstrate this, compile using for example GCC with the `-pedantic-errors` option to disable non-standard language extensions.

Comment: All uppercase identifiers are - by convention - used to denote template parameters when short (e.g. T, U, T2), otherwise preprocessor macros.  They should not be used for types.  A small matter, but enough to make me think whoever's given you your sample code doesn't have a clue.  Further, why have an array of pointers to `std::list` when you can just have an array of `std::list`?  It's less efficient and less maintainable (note - the deallocation code - another loop for `delete` - is missing from the sample).

Answer (score 2):

If this is C++, why not use `std`:

```
std::vector<std::list<MyClass> > x;
```

Comment: This is obviously a good answer but the OP tagged the question "homework", so I wouldn't be surprised if he can't use anything inside `std::`.

Comment: Forgot to include these two lines
    `typedef std::list<int> INT_LIST;
 typedef INT_LIST* INT_LIST_POINTER;`

Comment: @ereOn he uses `std::list` so `std::vector<INT_LIST_POINTER> myArray;` should be OK too.

Answer (score 2):

You allocate an array of size `p`:

```
INT_LIST_POINTER myArray = new INT_LIST[p];
```

and then proceed to initialize `n` elements:

```
for (int i=0; i<n; i++){
```

Unless `p` and `n` are the same thing, this doesn't look right.

P.S. Don't forget to `delete[] myArray` when you're done with it.

Comment: more importantly this allocates a fixed sized array yet again.

Comment: You are also correct, I have changed the wording in the original post, I do not need it to be fully dynamic.